# Select older date

Tags: sqlite

I have a database limited to n records, if a new record has to be inserted and there's no space I want to delete the oldest one, mind that there could be more than a record with same date: in this case I just remove the first one.
Is it possibile to achieve something like this in sqllite which doesn't have date support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to be able to sort your records by date, you have to insert them in the format `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYYMMDDHHmm`
Now to get one of oldest ones with same date, you can do this :

```
    SELECT * FROM URTABLE WHERE 
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE) FROM URTABLE) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It still works if I take in account time too? It would be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

Comment: exactly , this is because he compares them as TEXT, so you need the bigger units before the smaller ones Year > month > day > hour > minute